# create two vars in datatable R (divide operation)

Tags: r, data.table

I have a datatable with this columns. (Note : total is not  sum of A+B).

```
Date       Total     A      B
12-2015     10       2      3
01-2016     7        1      3
02-2016     15       8      3
```

I want add two variables one with percentage of A from total and b percentaje of B from total.

Anyone could help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can specify the columns in `.SDcols` and divide by 'Total' to assign it to new columns

```
dt[, paste0("Perc_", c("A", "B")) :=  .SD/Total, .SDcols = A:B]
dt
#     Date Total A B    Perc_A    Perc_B
#1: 12-2015    10 2 3 0.2000000 0.3000000
#2: 01-2016     7 1 3 0.1428571 0.4285714
#3: 02-2016    15 8 3 0.5333333 0.2000000
```